# Marketing Cloud Custom Activity

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

We need to call external REST API after sending email in journey builder.
Salesforce suggested using custom activity.

I looked into documentation and found very confusing or on high end development skills.

Before proceeding further I need to ask few questions which I am not sure.

Requirements:

1. Build Journey and send emails.
2. After sending email update a remote system using REST API with email details e:g email, subscriber key, date time email sent and few other details which saved in Data Extension.
3. After some time period (1 day) update same remote system if user have opened/not opened/clicked etc.

As I said at beginning I have looked into custom activity documentation and found it very difficult to follow, I am not sure about  inArguments/outArguments , what are these for?

Would any of you please guide me if it is possible at fist instance?

Kind Regards,

Comment: Custom activities are not an entry level task. For your level of expertise and use case, you should consider using a SSJS activity to send the rest calls , if they don't have to be real time.

Comment: We can get some one who can develop, but at this stage I want to know is it possible to send data to any end point from Journey Builder using custom activity.

While I was reading more about this after posting this question it seems it is possible but still not sure :(

Comment: Yes it is. In summary you have to host a webservice and pass the variables you want to send as inarguments to in the config.son file, to the webservice and make a post call via it

Comment: Thanks! I managed to create sample Custom Activity. So for so good :)